# Submit a form with href

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-5

I set the if of the form is as follows:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new {@id="frmHomeInsurance"}))
```

and instead of using a submit button, I would like to have a submit link.
So, I would like to replace the following:

```
<input type="submit" value="Get your quote now!" class="btn btn-default"/>
```

with the following:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Create", "HomeInsurance")" class="wow zoomIn" data-wow-delay="0.2s" onclick="document.forms['frmHomeInsurance'].submit(); return false;"><span class="fa fa-comments-o"></span>Get your<br>quote now!</a>
```

In theory, it should reach at my 'Create' action in my HomeInsurance controller, however, it's not.

Is there anything else I should declare before?

Update:
The action is as follows:

```
// POST: HomeInsurance/Create
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(HomeInsuranceModel model)
{
}
```

Comment: What is the method that generates this view - is it the `[HttpGet] Create()` method of `HomeInsuranceController`?

Comment: The GET method is what important :) (and I suggest you just use `href'#"` and remove the `return false;`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly use the href to submit the form. 
Create the form like this:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Create", "HomeInsurance", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{
    <define you form>
}
```

and then use your anchor tag to submit it(no href is needed):

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="wow zoomIn" data-wow-delay="0.2s" 
onclick="document.forms['frmHomeInsurance'].submit(); return false;">
   <span class="fa fa-comments-o"></span>Get your<br>quote now!
</a>
```

if you want to use the href you can do this but its not very pretty:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Create", "HomeInsurance")" 
onclick="var e=document.getElementById('yourFormId').action=this.href;e.submit();return false">
Submit</a>
```